# jquery define object outside the domcument.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, methods, load

i have a created object outside the jquery document.ready call and then calling that object methods from inside the document.ready. it works fine on firefox, but giving error in chrome. obviously if i put that object inside the document.ready, it works fine, but then i wont able to call that object from outside the document.ready. so i need solution for this. following is the code

```
var status = {
       method_one: function() { ...},
       method_two: function() { ...}
}

jquery(function() { // document ready
    status.method_one(); // giving error here in chrome, but does not in firefox.
});
```

Comment: maybe it's just a typo but it's supposed to be jQuery or $, case sensitive.

Comment: actually it works fine, if i rename it to feed or anything else other then status. thats really wired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works fine for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/5s739/

are you setting the `jquery` value yourself? Perhaps it should be `jQuery` with a capital **Q?**

```
var status = {
    method_one: function() { alert(1); },
    method_two: function() { alert(2); }
}

jQuery(function() {
    status.method_one();
});
```

you can probably test this quickly by checking if `$ == jquery` or `jQuery == jquery` unless you're assigning this yourself.

Comment: actually it works fine, if i rename it to feed or anything else other then status. thats really wired.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var status = null;

jquery(function() { // document ready
    status = {
       method_one: function() { ...},
       method_two: function() { ...}
    }
    status.method_one(); // giving error here in chrome, but does not in firefox.
});
```

Than you can still call status outside document.ready()